# Custom diamond shape in html or jscript

Tags: javascript, html

I need is some way to draw a shape in html. I've tried searching around, but I haven't found anything related.

Here is a sketch of what I need.

I need to draw shape in red. I know how to draw the dots, but I don't know how to connect them, because the red dots can move. The blue dots mark where the red dots can go.

[image]

Comment: Use javascript. there are many, many tutorials available online to do so,

Comment: Find tutorials on canvas.

Comment: Just to clear up the probable confusion stemming from the comments, both **SVG**  *&*  **Canvas** provide an API(easy to use commands) for creating shapes/drawings within a web-browser, each with it's own advantages/disadvantages. You might want to read up on each pros/cons, decide on one and then read a tutorial to get you started

Answer (score 2):

You could use a canvas. Here’s how you could draw a triangle:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
ctx.lineTo(100, 50);
ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)';
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150">Your browser lacks canvas support.</canvas>
```

I’ll leave it to you to figure out how to draw a diamond and make it red.

Comment: Gonna try this with more points, but it's problably the solution I want, more feedback when i finish tomorow ty dude :)